# Not getting proper soup object from website while scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am  trying to scrape yahoo finance website using BeautifulSoup and requests but not getting the correct soup. Its giving me a 404 page not found html code instead of giving me the original html code for the website . Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FBRX/profile?p=FBRX').text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Here is my output:
[image: Output Image]

Can you help me in scraping this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `User-Agent` HTTP header to obtain correct response from the server:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FBRX/profile?p=FBRX"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.h1.text)
```

Prints:

```
Forte Biosciences, Inc. (FBRX)
```

Comment: hey @andrej can you explain me in more detail about User-Agent HTTP Header. By the way thanks for the solution.

Comment: @AashishPal Every browser that connects to the server sens with the requests some HTTP headers (it's part of HTTP protocol). One of the header is `User-Agent` - it identifies the browser. Some of the servers are configured the way if the header is missing, it sends different response (many bots don't send any HTTP headers).